# Debug UWP Windows App on Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, winapi, uwp, windows-10

I have a UWP Javascript app. I'm using **Windows Runtime APIs** inside my app(for example: *Windows.Graphics.Display.DisplayInformation.getForCurrentView()*).

I'm successfully able to run the app using **Visual Studio 2015**.

But if I load my app in Google Chrome, I get ***"ReferenceError: Windows is not defined"***.

Is there any way to access **'Windows Runtime APIs'** on Google Chrome or any other way to mock/bypass ***'Windows'*** object related error.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You do not load your UWP *app* into Google Chrome. You load its source code. That is a world of a difference.

Answer (score 0):

No. Google Chrome doesn't give websites direct access to the Windows UWP API and never will.

Comment: thanks for reply. If it is not possible then can we integrate **Google Chrome Dev tools** in UWP app for debugging purposes?

Comment: No, but you can use Visual Studio.